# Print from command line across platforms

Tags: printing, command-line, command

I have an `appjs` application that creates images but I need to print these images. I'm aware I could write a utility app in Adobe AIR which would do the print for me but I'm sure there is a way to open the target systems default print preview utility from a command line interface.

I have Googled and found `lpr` for the mac but I don't seem to be able to get this to work. I've tried

```
lpr /path/to/my/image.jpg
```

But this doesn't seem to work?

On Windows I can use

```
print /path/to/my/image.jpg
```

But I haven't tested this, is there a command available on the cli on both platforms that opens the system default print preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that using `node-webkit` directly is both **MUCH** easier and printing works.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using app.js could you still not use basic JS, like window.print();

Comment: There's a known bug that this doesn't work in app.js, I'm currently downloading `node-webkit` to see if it's been implemented there. I think they've bailed on appjs :(